# Migrate from windowsazure.mediaservices to Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media

Tags: .net, azure-media-services

I have recently observed that windowsazure.mediaservices is deprecated and the documentation recommends using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.  I have not been able to find any documentation on the best way to do this migration.

Does anyone have a recommendation on the best approach to doing this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

windowsazure.mediaservices is the old v2 SDK (AMS v2).
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media is the SDK for AMS v3.
You need to migrate from AMS v2 to v3. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/migrate-v-2-v-3-migration-introduction

Comment: Thanks Xavier, that is correct - the very old windowsazure.mediaservices is based on the v2 API - We recently announced deprecation of that API and the migration guidance above is your best place to start.  We also have a lot of v3 API samples in this Git Hub repo for the .NET SDK - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/

Comment: I also have a repo with Node.js samples on v3 if you are interested in that - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials